# Email Templates "New Shipment"

Tags: email-templates, order-email, mail

We created an email template for (New Shipment)
in this template I use the variables : " Shipment Track Details, Shipment Items Grid, Shipment "  but when I receive the email the content of the variables is empty ,
on the back office side I filled in the information of tracking information.

I need to get the tracking info into the email content how can i do that ?

Comment: Can you please share the code

Comment: {{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}</td>
<td>{{var shipment}}

Comment: I think if you are triggering email from backend you have to change area="frontend". Also, edit answer give some more code properly if it's not working.